# WATIR: difference between link and link_element

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

when I ran my code with :

`link_element(:text, "#{user_name}").when_present.click` it gave error 
`TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer`

(Here user_name is variable which stores a string which is the name of user created run time with time stamp)

and when I ran my code with `link(:text, "#{content_title}").when_present.click` it gives
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'link' for #<ClassName:0x3ded7a0>`

This is the HTML of page:

```
<div class="univ_name">
  <p class="major_name" title="Thorin Oakenshield 04/05/15">
    <a href="/blabla/bla-bla-qwert-04-05-15-04-09-10-am">Thorin Oakenshield 04/05/15, 04:09:10 AM</a>
  </p>
  <div class="univ-info">
  <div class="univ-meta-data">
</div>
```

I also tried clicking using `link(:text, "#{user_name}").parent.paragraph(:class, 'major_name').parent.div(:class, 'univ_name').when_present.click` but no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The behaviour you are seeing is due to the differences between the Watir and the Page-Object APIs.

The first difference is in how elements are dynamically located:

- Watir uses `link` to find nested elements. For example, `browser.link(:text => "#{user_name}").click`
- The Page-Object gem uses `link_element` to find nested elements. For example, `page.link_element(:text => "#{user_name}").click`

Since `link` is only defined in Watir and not the Page-Object, page objects will give the undefined method error.

The second difference is how locators can be specified:

- Watir allows for the locator to be specified as a hash or as two arguments. Allowing two arguments is really only there for backwards compatibility; using a hash is often preferred. In other words, Watir allows both `browser.link(:text, "#{user_name}")` and `browser.link(:text => "#{user_name}")`.
- Page-Object only allows the locator to be specified as a hash - eg `browser.link(:text => "#{user_name}")`.

Since the `link_element` is called with two parameters instead of a single hash, an error occurs.

**Solution**

You should be able to solve your problem by using a hash with the `link_element` method:

```
link_element(:text => "#{user_name}").when_present.click
```

Comment: I was waiting for you to answer. Your answers leaves no question standing. I would really appreciate if you could quote examples with bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

No need for String interpolation, the below code works for me locally, when i set 'user_name' to the link text from the html given:

```
user_name = "Thorin Oakenshield 04/05/15, 04:09:10 AM"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "http://127.0.0.1:1234/"
browser.link(:text, user_name).when_present.click
```